# USB NES controller

Tags: controllers

I just recently bought the [Retrolink USB NES Controller](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005Y5NO4U).

I would really like to make simple platformer games (for PC - engine/ frame/ library doesn't matter) for this pretty popular retro controller. But **I can't find a website associated with the company** where I could find either **dev tool/ sdks** or a **library of existing games**.

Ever since I bought this controller I did nothing, but testing the buttons. - I didn't even find a game that supports it 100% and I don't own an NES.

Comment: Are you on Windows? I think Windows will present that controller as  a joystick, you should be able to read it's state with standard input libraries.

Comment: I figured some unity games work.
They apparently detect it as an input device with vertical and horizontal axis as well as four buttons.

My question remains..do they have a website - who are these people that designed it. I don't feel right about this product.

Comment: @bornander On GNU/Linux, SDL is a safe bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have explained, controllers (especially simple controllers like these) are supposed to work out of the box, with the standard input libraries of your operating system (DirectInput in Windows).

It seems like you're interested in knowing who makes these, so I tried a bit of google, and found that "RetroLink" [is a registered trademark](http://www.trademarkia.com/retrolink-77946248.html) of a USA company called "Kool Brands LLC" registered in Reno, Nevada.

From what I could see in a [low resolution scan of the back](http://img.banggood.com/images/upload/2012/panxihua/SKU106246/you/SKU106246%20(5).jpg) of another controller of the same brand, the bottom part barely reads "???????? and RetroLink ????? are trademarks of Kool Brands LLC", which corroborates this information.

They [also seem to hold trademarks](http://www.trademarkia.com/company-kool-brands-llc-3905181-page-1-2) for "GameBully", "Robokit", "Exo-Guard", "Buck-Shot", "Retro gen" and "Sumoto". All game controller related.

They don't seem to have a website, but you can find more information about this company if you google them.

From what I see, they seem to be a tiny operation, probably solely a trademark holding company, and the RetroLink products are very likely rebranded generic chinese products.

I don't think they will have SDKs or other information like those you're looking for.

Googling a bit further, it seems like Kool Brands LLC is deeply involved with another company, which does have a website, called [Innex](http://www.innexinc.com/). They sell RetroLink as well as other brands. If you have specific questions about the RetroLink products, they may be able to help you.